# Could not load file or assembly 'Quartz, Version=3.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4'

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net, quartz

I have a .NET Standard project in which i have installed Quartz.NET from NuGet package. I have to get all the types in this dll/assembly which implement a specific interface. I iterate over all the types in this assembly and check if the type implements the specific interface. My code is:

```
foreach (Type t in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
{
    if (t.GetInterface(nameof(MyInterface), true) != null)
         // logic
}
```

Now issue is that i get the following exception in foreach loop:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Quartz, Version=3.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I don't know why i am getting this exception. Quartz.NET dll is there in my .NET Standard project. I have cleaned/rebuild the solution but still no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.